# Calling a method from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, dynamic

I have an ASP webpage which I am trying to write some javascript in...

I want to set a variable to the response of a function - which is stored in my code behind (page.aspx.vb).

this is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var test ='<%GetTestName()%>'
</script>
```

I run this page - which does call the method GetTestName()... but does not set the variable 'test' to the response. In the dynamic view, I can just see that this line of JavaScript now says:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var test =''
</script>
```

This method is used a number of times in this ASP listview control - and works fine. For example:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="rlvI" style="height:100px; width:100px; margin-top:0px; margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:25px; background-color:<%# GetRowColor(Container.DataItem)%>; color:white">
            <asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" CssClass="rlvBEdit" Text=" " ToolTip="Select" />
             <asp:Label ID="measure" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("measure")%>' />
            <br />
             <asp:Label ID="actualLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Concat("A: ", Eval("actual"))%>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="budgetLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Concat("B: ", Eval("budget"))%>' />
            <br />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Is this not possible in javascript? And if not can you suggest a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var test ='<%=GetTestName()%>'
</script>
```

Note the '=' sign.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>` to your function signature, you can use PageMethods to call the method from javascript as so.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>_
Public Shared Function MethodName()
    'dostuff
End Function
```

You will also have to add a Scriptmanager to your page.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function functionName()
{
    PageMethods.MethodName();
}
```